# How to grab my poster image from HTML and implement it in JavaScript once I rewind/reset video?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to work in DOM level 2 with JavaScript. I load up my video with a poster as seen in the code below from my HTML file.

```
<video id = "myVideo" width="1024" height="600" poster="images/poster.jpg">
```

This loads my image into my video for the start (as a poster) from my HTML. However, when I pause it or scroll my slider back to the beginning the poster does not display again.

I want to be able to grab that Image from the HTML and write the code in a separate JavaScript file for when I pause or restart the video using controls. For example:

```
//add an event listener here that grabs the poster image from the HTML above('', onPause)

function onPause()
{
   //display that image that I have grabbed
}
```

I feel like it has something to do with HTMLImageElement but I am unsure.

Comment: Just copy the path to the image from the video element's poster attribute to the src attribute of an image element ..?

Comment: You will have to show an overlay once the video is pause. like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24519136/2630817

Comment: So I created a variable which I then assigned the location of the images to an src within my JS but I didn't know how to then display it. Not sure if that's what you meant... @Teemu

Comment: Thanks. I did see this example but I feel like there is definitely a better way to do it but somehow just grabbing the image and displaying it. If not then I will happily go with this... @Justcode